How to reliably find audio interface recordings in mobile phone recordings
For scientific research, I recorded a few singers with several devices in a recording room. Two of these devices were proper microphones connected to an audiointerface, and they were positioned right before the singer's mouths. Two others were smartphones which I placed at different locations in the room. Therefore, the acoustics of the recordings are a bit different.
The recordings consists of several different vowels sang at different ranges.
I cut the audiointerface recordings into individual snippets, each containing a single vowel with a duration of about 300 ms to 3 s at most.
I would like to match these snippets with corresponding snippets from the smartphone recordings. Currently, I am using the cross-correlation method which appears to work in about 60-70% of cases, but yields quite a few incorrect matches. Is there some better way to find the snippets in the long, uncut smartphone recordings automatically?

hm cross-correlation should be the maximum likelihood estimator here (some very large simplifying assumptions made there), so your 60% success rate seems a bit low. Are you sure you're normalizing correlation results correctly by the energy?

Currently I use the unnormalized cross correlation, which is what is suggested in several places. I also tried Matlab's findsignal function with energy and mean normalization ('Normalization', 'zscore'), see https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findsignal.html. It also did not yield reliable results. From my own signal processing expertise, one would have to compute local estimates of the standard deviation of the mobile phone signal and then compute the normalized cross correlation pointwise. This should be equivalent to matlab's findsignal function.

exactly; that should be as good as you get in a low-multipath, additive noise scenario. Now, the main problem is that you have multipath, so you might have a few problems with imprecise timing, but honestly, this usually works well – after all, you've got Cauchy-Schwarz on your side, saying that nothing correlates as well with your own signal as a scalar multiple of it, and if you normalize by the product of reference and reception RMS (which you elegantly called "local estimates of stddev"), then you'd get the best possible estimator, in a pure AWGN channel; now yours clearly isn't AWGN,

so maybe it helps if you low-pass filter to say 800 Hz or 1 kHz first? My hypothesis is that anything above is going to be worse in SNR, since there's not too much vocal power at high frequencies, and more subject to frequency selectivity, because wavelengths are shorter and coherence bandwidths hence smaller relative to the frequency.

If that doesn't help, maybe comparing MFCC vectors would? From there on, it becomes a bit more interesting, with HMMs and things you'd probably do with deep neural networks these days

Thank you! I will try low-pass filtering the signal next :) I considered MFCCs, but hoped for some standard algorithm that is known to be reliable (and goes beyond the cross-correlation).

Extraction was way more reliable using https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mueen/FastestSimilaritySearch.html, which comes down to the segmentwise estimate of the correlation coefficient as discussed with Marcus. It is way faster than Matlab's findsignal function and also more reliable.
